# Mostrar una alerta con sweetalert en PHP si el usuario hace click en botón

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sweetalert

Estoy haciendo una web en la que el usuario puede añadir a favoritos animales, y quiero mostrar con SweetAlert una alerta cuando el usuario haya hecho la acción de pulsar el botón y se haya añadido correctamente a favoritos, pero no me sale nada, en cambio si lo hago sin sweet alert si me salta el alert.

Este es el principio del código (donde incluyo php) donde tengo el html que hace la llamada a la clase y a la función para ejecutar la consulta si el usuario pulsa el botón de favoritos:

```
session_start();
    require ('index.php');
    
    
    // Si existe nombre y id lo obtiene a través del get
if (isset($_GET['nombre']) && isset($_GET['id'])) :
    // Obtenemos el nombre y el id
    $nombre_perro = $_GET['nombre']; 
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    // Obtienes datos desde la nueva función
    // Instanciamos el objeto
    $obj = new Animales();
    // Llamamos a la funcion
    $datos = $obj->visualizarById($id);
endif;

//si pulsa el boton de favorito se llama a la funcion añadir y se añade a favorito
if (isset($_POST['add']) && isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) : 
    if(!$addfav = $obj->add($id,$_SESSION['usuario']->id)): 
     
        ?>
     
           
        
    <?php                else:
        echo "<script>
           swal('Good job!', 'You clicked the button!', 'success');
                </script>";
        header("Refresh:0");
    
        endif;

 elseif (isset($_POST['add']) && !isset($_SESSION['usuario'])):
        header("location:login.php"); 
    
endif;
```

SweetAlert lo he añadido en un archivo que incluye los archivos que necesita mi programa:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssanimales.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssportada.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pruebadesp.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="vistausuario.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

Parte donde incluyo scripts en el codigo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<?php require "head.php" ?>
<tittle><?php $datos->nombre;?></tittle> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    require "navegacion.php";
   
    ?>
```

Comment: Hola, me parece que lo puedes hacerlo de dos formas, una: escuchar el evento `click` de tu boton favoritos `const boton = document.getElementById('id_boton' )` despues `boton.addEventListener('click', ()=> alert('añadido a favoritos') )` o hacer un `echo "<script>alert('añadido')</script>";` justo antes de tu `header("Refresh:0");`

Comment: ambas están bien, muchas gracias! con alert normal me funciona pero estoy intentando hacerlo con sweet alert  y no me funciona

Comment: Pregunta actualizada @masterguru

Comment: ok, con sweet alert te recomiendo usar la funcion del Evento, es decir, `addEventListener('click', ()=>{  Swal.fire({  icon: 'seccess', title: 'añadido a favoritos', confirmButtonText: 'OK', }); } `, y en `<head>` añade el cdn de sweetAlert, para que funcione.

Comment: viendo tu edición de la pregunta: solo añade el `swal.fire({});`, es decir, `Swal.fire({  icon: 'seccess', title: 'añadido a favoritos', confirmButtonText: 'OK',});` y en `<head>` añade el cdn de sweetAlert (que veo que si lo tienes), para que funcione.

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar @Artes  quizá es porque el head está debajo del código php? y por lo tanto no encuentra la libreria que añadí

Comment: @NereaVázquez puede ser, por lo regular cuando ocupo sweetAlert lo pongo arriba, después el código, puedes hacer un `echo ' <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>'` hasta arriba del php a ver si funciona.

Comment: @Artes sigue sin funcionarme

Comment: Alguna alerta en la consola?

Comment: @Artes he probado a hacer un require head.php al principio del codigo y también justo antes del script y no sale nada, ninguna alerta. en la consola no hay erorres

Comment: Si es un error del swal, lo va a lanzar cuando hagas el click? Lo has revisado?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136000/discussion-between-nerea-vazquez-and-artes).